# users dialogs database scheme

Tags: ruby-on-rails, database-design

I want to create users dialog

How I must do?

Create one record with sender_id and recipient_id and then "select * from table_dialog where sender_id=current.id or recipient_id =current.id" also add 2 columns deleted_by_sender and deleted_by_recipient

Or create 2 record in database for each dialog

What is the best solution? Or propose your own solution please

Comment: Can you clear up your question?  Do you want a schema?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If by "dialog" you mean a "conversation between TWO participants", then it is very similar to classic mailbox. The following code extract(with abbreviation) from one of my project which implements similar functionality. Maybe will be helpful.

```
class User < ActiveRecord::Base
  # ....
  has_many :received_messages, :class_name => "Message", :foreign_key => 'recipient_id'
  has_many :sent_messages, :class_name => "Message", :foreign_key => 'sender_id'
  # ....
end

class Message < ActiveRecord::Base
  validates :content, :presence => true
  validates :sender, :presence => true, :associated => true
  validates :recipient, :presence => true, :associated => true

  belongs_to :sender, :class_name => 'User', :foreign_key => 'sender_id'
  belongs_to :recipient, :class_name => 'User', :foreign_key => 'recipient_id'

  default_scope order('created_at desc')

  # usage: user.received_messages.unread
  scope :unread, where('unread = true')

  def self.chat_between(first_user, second_user)
    where('(recipient_id = ? AND sender_id = ?) OR (recipient_id = ? AND sender_id = ?)',
            first_user.id, second_user.id, second_user.id, first_user.id)
  end

  def self.read_all!
    self.update_all('unread = false')
  end

  def read!
    self.update_attribute :unread, false
  end

  def new?(user)
    (recipient == user) && (unread == true)
  end

end
```